# How to reduce the space between the header and an iframe in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this page http://34.238.252.129/percentage-gains/ which is being rendered by wordpress. I'm using this theme https://wordpress.org/themes/vast/. The table you see is inside an iframe, such that the content is coming from another page. How do I reduce the space between the header and the iframe? I want it to be almost at the upper edge.

For future reference, here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not really WordPress specific, but rather just css.  You can add this via the customizer or your theme style sheet.

```
.page-id-6 main#content {
    margin: 0 0 96px;
}
```

`.page-id-6` ensures that it only has a margin-top of 0 on that specific page.